# How to use GCM notification sync

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I know that in never version of GCM you can dismiss notifications based on userId and not device id. This essentially syncs this action with all devices that user is using with same google account. Documentation page for this can be found here and it is quite helpful

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html

Only thing I don't understand from there is:
Do I need to write code in my app to contact the GCM sever or my own server to trigger dismissal on other devices or does this happen automatically when notification is dismissed or opened ?

This is the part that led me to think that you need to do it manually but I am not certain :
"You should design your app to handle cases where the app receives a dismissal message, but has not yet displayed the notification that is being dismissed."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to write code in your app to trigger the dismissal message, as well as handle it.

> Note: A notification dismissal message is like any other upstream message, meaning that it will be delivered to the other devices that belong to the specified notification_key. You should design your app to handle cases where the app receives a dismissal message, but has not yet displayed the notification that is being dismissed. You can solve this by caching the dismissal and then reconciling it with the corresponding notification.

This makes sense, because GCM doesn't know how your app handles an arriving GCM message. Your app might display a notification (which needs to be dismissed if it was already handled on another device belonging to the same user), or it might perform some background sync with the server (in which case no dismissal message needs to be sent).

The point of this new feature is that you send a single message to a single notification key instead of sending it to multiple registration IDs, and an app installed on any of the devices belonging to the same user doesn't need to know the registration IDs of all those devices. It only needs to know the notification_key in order to communicate with the other devices.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I find this kind of logical but the point of this new feature pointless since only new thing is referring to group of devices by one identifier instead of a list. Same thing was possible before this, you just had to send multicast message to user devices and define dismissal message by yourself. I am kind of disappointed by this fact but your answer is great and was exactly what I was looking for. Only thing that would also be helpful would be a link to some example of best practise implementation so if you know about some please add it for feature reference.

Answer (score 0):

i think its your serer that need to be contacted
this keeps the flow consistence and also , when contacting GCM server to send message you need to provide your API-key and project Id ... and this is critical to be stored on the mobile application.

thats why you should contact your server, in his turn, your server will contact GCM server

this is my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So I do have to trigger the sync message manually? I kind of don't get the point of this new feature then. Because all older apps would have to be rewritten to use this and you could have done it before this by defining your own clear notification message and sending those to user devices.

Comment: well, after a second look, and more search, i found that it should be  sent by mobile app to all devices registered using same google account BUT it will use notification_key, which is a key acquired just like regId from GCM server, that represents multi devices under same google account, and at first place when u r send message you should use notification_key to (not sure)... have a look here ... some interesting info http://captechconsulting.com/blog/antoine-campbell/google-cloud-messaging-cloud-connection-server-tutorial